# Salesforce Invitation Survey URL is not working

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforce-survey

We use Salesforce Surveys to send Surveys to our customers. These survey records are automatically created whenever a transaction gets completed in the salesforce. The Survey link is specific to the customer/transaction.

For the last three weeks, we have been facing an issue wherein the Survey URL is not working as expected.

We are getting the below error message when we try to access the survey for feedback.

> Error Message: An error occurred. Contact Salesforce Customer Support with the Salesforce Error ID.

But it’s working fine in the sandbox instance.

Prod Survey URL - https://portal.dmcc.ae/survey/runtimeApp.app?invitationId=0Ki5F0000008ONV&surveyName=transaction_survey_2020&UUID=480b3371-de5c-40d9-ad68-9135c4cae140

Sandbox Survey URL - https://dmccsf--uat.sandbox.my.site.com/customer/survey/runtimeApp.app?invitationId=0Ki5F000000g9vK&surveyName=transaction_survey_2020&UUID=9add0c73-0c41-4be4-8c14-6b3de332cd16

Please let me know if anyone else has faced this issue and the resolution.

[image]